# How to use two switches in vhdl

Tags: switch-statement, vhdl, fpga, xilinx

I want to control the value of a variable using two switches. One for incrementing the value, whereas the other one for decrementing the value.  How should i shange this code.
error says that the variable counting is unsynthesisable. 
I have tried a lot but could not figure out what exactly the problem is.

> ERROR:Xst:827 - line 34: Signal counting0 cannot be synthesized, bad synchronous description. The description style you are using to describe a synchronous element (register, memory, etc.) is not supported in the current software release.

```
library IEEE;
    use IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;
    use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

entity counts is
port(
        btn_up  : in std_logic;
        reset : IN  STD_LOGIC;
        btn_dn  : in std_logic;
        counted : out std_logic_vector(8 downto 0)
        );
end entity counts;

architecture behaviour of counts is
  signal counter : std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);
begin

  btupprocess : process(btn_up,reset,counter)
    variable counting : unsigned(8 downto 0);
  begin
    counting := unsigned(counter);
    if(reset = '1') then
      counting := (others => '0');
    elsif (rising_edge(btn_up)) then
      if(counting > 399) then
        counting := counting - 1;
      else
        counting := counting + 1;
      end if;
    end if;
    counter <= std_logic_vector(counting);
  end process;

  btndnprocess : process(btn_dn,counter)
    variable counting : unsigned(8 downto 0);
  begin
    counting := unsigned(counter);
    if (falling_edge(btn_dn)) then
      if(counting < 200) then
        counting := counting + 1;
      else
        counting := counting - 1;
      end if;
    end if;
    counter <= std_logic_vector(counting);
  end process;
  counted <= counter;
end behaviour;
```

Comment: The unsupported behaviour is driving Counter from two different processes.

Comment: You should just use one process on the above code, not 2.  Another issue you're going to have is that you need to make sure you debounce the button input.  Google the word debounce for more information about this.

Answer (score 1):

Although in some cases it is possible to drive a signal from two different processes, there are better approaches in this case.

A possible solution to your problem is:

- add a `clock` input to your entity; you should probably use a synchronous design
- rewrite your architecture to use three processes, with each process driving a single signal:

  - one process will debounce and detect a rising edge on `btn_up`; this process will generate the signal `btn_up_rising_edge`
  - one process will debounce and detect a rising edge on `btn_dn`; this process will generate the signal `btn_dn_rising_edge`
  - a third process will read `btn_up_rising_edge` and `btn_dn_rising_edge`, and increment or decrement the count as appropriate
- in all three processes, your sensitiviy list should contain `clock` and `reset` only

You can find an example of an edge detector with a debouncer here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/32260/vhdl-debouncer-circuit